# Load an Assembly into an AppDomain

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, appdomain

I have written a .dll that loads other .dlls at runtime. This works really well on the desktop. I am using the following code to achieve that:

```
Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.Load("somePath");
```

The problem I am having is that I need to reuse this .dll in my web app. However, after I am done calling my code I need to unload the assembly for clean up on the web server.

I keep trying to use an AppDomain but I keep getting the exception that the library or one of its dependencies do not exist.

```
AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyNewDomain");
myDomain.Load("SomePath.dll");
```

Didn't work

```
AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup() {  };
Evidence domainEvidence = new Evidence();
domainEvidence.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.Trusted));
PermissionSet permissions = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(domainEvidence);

AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain, domainEvidence, domainSetup, permissions, null);
myDomain.Load("SomePath.dll");
```

Same Result

I have read numerous Microsoft/Stackoverflow articles on AppDomains and have not gotten any further.

If anyone has any further knowledge I would greatly appreciate it.

---

UPDATE

When I Try to add a AssemblyResolve event I get the following exception:

Type is not resolved for member

```
myDomain.AssemblyResolve += myDomain_AssemblyResolve;
```

Comment: Have you looked into wiring up the `AssemblyResolve` event on the new `AppDomain`?

Comment: @Parrish Husband See my update

Comment: Hmm, are you passing objects across AppDomain boundaries?

Comment: I need to use the foreign .dll to parse data files, then I need to unload the foreign .dll. I use the parsed data files in my current AppDomain.

Comment: If the parsed data files are in a class you designed, you likely need to implement `MarshalByRef` on it to have it serialize properly when passing between App Domains.  If it's coming through as just a data string, there may be something else going on.